# Термины C#. Входные и выходные параметры

Tags: c#

Я знаю что такое параметр, ref, out, in, return и как это работает, но не понимаю что такое "входные параметры" и "выходные параметры". В русской документации таких словосочетаний не нашел. [Документация 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) пункт 1.6.6.1 гласит (вроде верно перевел)

> Ссылочный параметр используется для передачи как входных, так и выходных параметров. Ссылочный параметр объявляется с модификатором ref. Выходной параметр объявляется с модификатором out.

ref, out, in - все они передаются по ссылке, значит все они "входные и выходные"? Или как тогда правильно?

Comment: "Выходной параметр объявляется с модификатором out" - Вам же написано ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Входные параметры - это параметры, которые передаются в функцию (записываются в скобках при ее объявлении) и нужны для работы функции. `out` - выходной параметр. Выходные параметры - это результат выполнения функции (обычно пишутся после `return`.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov да, out - выходной, можно ли его назвать входным? Если да/нет то почему?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Если входные это те, что записываются в скобках, то в чем отличие от обычных параметров? А если я устанавливаю значение по умолчанию, то данный параметр тоже входной? И откуда интересно он вошел? return - выходной параметр? Пришло X, вернул 0, где тут параметр? возвращаемое значение - да, но никак не параметр. PS "функции" в шарпе нет, есть либо "метод", либо "локальная функция"

Comment: @Enifan, нельзя. Так как его значение не может использоваться функцией, ибо она считает, что его нет.

Comment: @Enifan, не слушайте Виталия, ибо он не отличает результата (или возвращаемого значения) от параметров.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov спасибо, у меня была такая мысль, просто хотел уточнить.
А что насчет модификаторов ref и in?
Как я понял ref - входной и выходной, in - входной. Правильно ли я думаю ?

Comment: @Enifan, yep. in (и просто параметр без модификаторов) - in, out - out, ref - in/out

Comment: Вышеуказанный комментарий является ответом на вопрос, кто нибудь может отметить его как "верный ответ"? я не пойму как это делать

Comment: @Enifan, комментарии - это комментарии, галочки можно ставить только на ответы, а ответы я уже давно принципиально не оформляю